# making an already existing app paid

Tags: android

I have a free app in android play store.
Now I want to give user 2 options.
One free and the other paid where the paid app has no advertisements and other feature enhancements

Is there a way to do so in Android?

Comment: I would use in-app billing to allow users of the app to perform a one-off purchase to remove adverts and enable features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could get this in different ways.

As @Ken Wolf said you could add a system in your exists app which could let the user to pay to remove ads from the same application they have without the need to install a different version. With this system you have only one APK and you should check if the user has paid the application if yes enable pro features and disable ads.

Or, if you want to create two different versions you could create a basic application and a "pro" and using a [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) to keep an unique code shared between the two versions.

And, of course the code of the "pro" features will be only in the pro APK version... same for resources, layouts, drawable etc.

Other answers i found for you:

- [Best approach for Free and Paid versions of Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695010/best-approach-for-free-and-paid-versions-of-android-application)
- [Best way to have paid and free version of an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711967/best-way-to-have-paid-and-free-version-of-an-android-app)

Comment: the first option is your best choice if your using google play, as it is against the terms of service to have two versions of the same app in publication